# What Eclipse should I download if I program in java?

Tags: java, eclipse

On the [Eclipse site, there are several Eclipse downloads](http://eclipse.org/downloads/), which one I should pick?

This - [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigosr2)

This - [Eclipse Classic 3.7.2](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-372/indigosr2)

Or this - [Eclipse IDE for Java Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/indigosr2)

Now I'm programming regular Java applications, 2d graphics (awt, graphics2d, etc..) and in the future JSP.

Comment: why saying jsp is "not your choice!", it can be efficient when well used ;-)

Comment: They now have a comparison chart and one can select a few to narrow the field: [Compare Eclipse Packages](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For general Java programming the Eclipse Classic would be appropriate.

If you want to do web development, then I suggest the Java EE variant, which is suitable for JSP (it also contains everything the Classic variant does).

Comment: Thanks I downloaded eclipse for Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers

Comment: Cool. Then consider marking my answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 3):

Pick "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" for now. It does everything except JSPs. When you reach the stage where you want to work on JSPs - you can just do an upgrade your Eclipse and add the EE features.

Comment: +1 by the time you know enough J2SE to go into J2EE, Eclipse might go through 3 versions.

Answer (score 1):

Any of the packages will do the "regular java programs" and the "2d" stuff.  "3d" stuff will require extra libraries which can be added to any of the offerings; but, "jsp" stuff will be much easier to develop with the Java EE offerings.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you the 2nd option  i.e. Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers ,because if in future  you want to develop Web based application then it will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're going to be doing web based work in the future. I suggest the EE version (enterprise edition)